# How to use Vue in laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am going through vue 2 laracast videos I am stuck in the 1st tutorial itself.

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>@{{ message }} </h1>
  <input type= "text" id="input" v-model = "message">
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>


<script >
    var data = {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    })
</script>
```

don't work, gives an error

Use of undefined constant message - assumed 'message'

```
@{{ message }}
```

gives me the result then proceeding to v-model gives an empty input box no message.

Comment: what version of laravel are you using? what version of laravel are they using in the videos?

Comment: your code is correct and iI tested it in Laravel

Comment: @lagbox I am using laravel 5.4 in tutorial they used plain html

Comment: the answer is [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337831/vue-js-component-not-working-in-laravel-blade-file).

Comment: @Amin adding @ display Hello Vue! but not v-model input text